# Moodle - Cannot view enrolled users in a course

Tags: php, moodle

I have a Moodle site with a few courses. I have created a test course, and created a new Teacher user. I am trying to assign this teacher to this test course, but I am having some difficulties doing so.

First, I logged in as Admin, went to the course page, and turned on editing.

Next, under Course Administration, I clicked Users, then I clicked 'Enrolled users'. (I am doing this, to assign the teacher to this course)

The page loads, but returns a blank page. There is nothing on the page. I tried this a few times, but no luck.

The url of this blank page is like this: http://www.MoodleWebsiteNameGoesHere.com/lms/enrol/users.php?id=17

This seems to be an unusual problem on Moodle.

Also, I get a blank page when clicking on 'Other users', but when I click on 'Enrollment methods', the enrollment methods page loads.

Can you guys help me?

FYI: I am running a Moodle 2.6 installation

Comment: probably a bug somewhere, go to site admin -> development and switch on debugging level to developer and display debug messages to on - then try to display the page - although if its a production site, might be better to take a database dump and test locally

Comment: Hi Russell, I did as you said, and it said that: require_once(/home/username/public_html/lms/enrol/locallib.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/username/public_html/lms/enrol/users.php on line 26. This means that the locallib.php is missing, right?

Comment: It does - it could possibly be a permissions thing too, check if the file is there - if it is, then its permissions, if it isn't then its missing :) If you check the version of moodle in /home/username/public_html/lms/version.php then you can grab a copy of the missing file on github by choosing the tag - eg for 2.6.7: https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/v2.6.7/enrol